# The $_POST data is empty even though I'm getting a 200 response on the POST?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, flightphp

I've got a PHP application that uses [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) for the client, [FlightPHP](http://flightphp.com/) for REST services, and PHP in the back end.

However, even though I'm issuing a `POST` with this code here:

```
$scope.registerUser = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/user/register',
        data: $scope.user
    }).success(function(data) {
                if (data.result === undefined) {
                    setAjaxMessage(data, false);
                    return;
                }

                if (data.result === 0) {
                    setAjaxMessage(data.message, true);
                }
                else {
                    setAjaxMessage(data.message, false);
                }
            }).error(function(data) {
                setAjaxMessage(data, false);
            });
};
```

**and** I'm getting a successful `POST` message via Firefox with the `Params -> Request payload` tab set to this data:

```
{"displayname":"user1","email":"user1@gmail.com","password":"abc123"}
```

when I issue this server-side:

```
Flight::route('POST /user/register', function() {
    echo var_dump($_POST);
    return;

    // register the user
    require 'core/register.php';
});
```

I get this:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

What gives here? I've never had an issue with the `$_POST` data before. I have a feeling it has something to do with FlightPHP, but I can't put my finger on it. It's getting into the handler for the `POST` as you can see.

Comment: What exact output do you see for your `var_dump`? PS: `var_dump` outputs by itself, you don't need additional `echo` in front of it

Comment: @zerkms, sorry I messed up the post while I was editing. Please see my edit.

Comment: What if you perform `var_dump($_POST);` in that framework's entry point as the first line? Before framework had a chance to drop it.

Comment: @zerkms, exact same result.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be sending JSON instead of url encoded key value pairs?

Comment: @Musa, you would be 100% correct on that, it is JSON.

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate question but the last line of this answer is what you're after - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15711147/283366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this one is a bit funky. But it **is** because of FlightPHP. Normally, the answer provided by Mike Brant would be 100% correct! However, FlightPHP reads that input before I can, and according to the PHP documentation it *can only be read once*.

So, where does FlightPHP put it? Ha, now that's an odd one. They put it in a property named `body`, so I had to do this to grab those JSON values:

```
$vars = json_decode(Flight::request()->body, true);
```

The `Flight::request()->body` returns the JSON string. But then that needs decoded and turned into an associative array, so that's why I'm passing the `true` as the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you for this! I was stuck on this same problem and almost gave up.

Comment: @izolate, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: "according to the PHP documentation it can only be read once", do you have the reference? I am also confused by this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to get your data from PHP's raw input if you are not posting a form-encoded query string (like is the case for raw JSON).  Here is how you can read your JSON data into an appropriate PHP data structure:

```
$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

You should also explicitly set the Content-type header as follows:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/user/register',
    data: $scope.user,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).success(function(data) {
  // rest of your code
```

Comment: This worked for me!  Coding php for 13 years and this is the first time I've come across this one. Thanks!

Comment: When data are successfully sent, but $_POST is empty. I confirm that instead, json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')) works like a charm. So thanks !