# Passing variable from view to http post using AngularJS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am taking first steps with angular here and breaking my head about two stuff.
the first is i cant pass variable from the view to http.post call.

in this index.html `ng-click` passes the correct values:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
       <td><a href="{{data.link}}" target="_blank">{{data.songName}}</td>
       <td>{{data.artist}}</td>
       <td><a ng-click="deleteSong(data.songName, data.artist, data.link)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and in app.js the deleSong function looks like this:

```
$scope.deleteSong = function($songName, $artist, $link) {
    // Posting data to php file
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'ajax/deleteSong.php',
        data    : $scope.data, //forms user object
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
        .success(function(data) {

            if (data.errors) {
                // Showing errors.
                $scope.errorSong= data.errors.song;
                $scope.errorArtist= data.errors.artist;
                $scope.errorLink= data.errors.link;
            } else {
                $scope.message = data.message;
            }
        });
    $scope.user = null
}
```

and finally , deleteSong.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include('../includes/config.php');

$errors = array();
$data = array();
// Getting posted data and decodeing json
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$song = $_POST['song'];

$query="DELETE FROM songs WHERE songName = '$song'";
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

echo $query;
?>
```

When i click the delete song icon, the function get called but the response i get is this:

`DELETE FROM songs WHERE songName = ''`

any idea what am i missing and why is the query not getting the data i passed to `deleteSong.php`?

Comment: what is the output of  print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: i tried checking but it is empty...

Comment: I would check the data sent by the POST request angular is making using the browser inspector tools.

Comment: You are sending $scope.data in the POST request, but you are passing $songName, $artist and $link to the function. When are you setting the $scope.data variable that you are setting as the data for the POST request? By the way, why naming the parameters with a $ before?

Comment: too many `data`.... why not simply declare `$scope.deleteSong = function( _data) {` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you code as follows, You are taking the data as parameter of your ng-clik function. but you are not using those. Rather you are trying $scope.data (Which is something else). So change the code as follows.

```
$scope.deleteSong = function($songName, $artist, $link) {
// Posting data to php file
$http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : 'ajax/deleteSong.php',
    data    : {'song':$songName},//Changed Line Here 
    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
    .success(function(data) {

        if (data.errors) {
            // Showing errors.
            $scope.errorSong= data.errors.song;
            $scope.errorArtist= data.errors.artist;
            $scope.errorLink= data.errors.link;
        } else {
            $scope.message = data.message;
        }
    });
$scope.user = null
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning $_POST['song'] to the $song variable but it does not exist in the $_POST-array. Please replace `$_POST['song']` with `$_POST['songName']`

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue, 
in your php file, instead of using `$_POST` try to use `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`
([have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707431/http-post-using-angular-js))

That might work assuming all the rest is without bugs...
Ensure, with a console.log, that $songName, $artist, $link variables contain the correct value...

just a note, **never use variables with `$` because dollar is used for private angularjs variables**